# Code made on VS2017 for mac don't work on VS2017 for Windows

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2017

I'm not a developer but I needed to code a simple web page for a POC.

For that I used VS2017 for mac to make a MVC project and all is fine when I run it on "my machine" (yeah I know it a common issue :P), I mean I can build the solution and open the web page, this page is used to create/register an user at AWS Cognito.

But when I run this same solution in a windows machine with Visual Studio 2017, the project builds without errors the web page opens but I can't make the API calls to aws cognito, this machine has open access to internet, so it's not a network problem.

I think it can be a software problem, I'm using  C# and .NET 4.5 + the AWS SDKs referent to the project.

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you open up your browser's development tools and go to the "console" section, you may find one or more errors listed. These errors will likely be useful in troubleshooting. If the API calls are made in C#, you should have logs stored somewhere, or can run the program with VS's debugging tools and uncover error messages that way.

Comment: can you post the code which makes the API call?

Comment: If you are using .NET Framework this won't work, you need to use .NET Core if you want cross platform apps

Comment: I cant see any errors on browser's devtools, it just be waiting for a server response. On VS's debugging tools its all fine there are no errors.

Follow the code https://pastebin.com/YnGqCvVF

Comment: @hellyale How can I move my code from .NET 4.5 to .NET Core?

Comment: @NikolasWostor start a new project that targets .NET CORE in Visual Studio, then move your classes into it. Some tweaks might be necessary... not 100% sure this is your issue